# CSS Selectors - Determining even/odd children starting with last child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, html-email

Using CSS only, is there a way to apply and even/odd count starting with the last-child element and going backward to the first-child? I can't use JavaScript for this project; this is for emails generated from a database for Silverpop.

I have a table with several rows that need to alternate background colors. These rows are generated from a database, so they number anywhere from 3 to 6 rows. The last row always needs to be white because immediately following that is a table with a grey background, and I can't have the last row be grey. I'll have a fallback for those email clients that don't support E:nth-of-type.

tr:nth-of-type(even) { grey } would work for 3 rows:

```
<table>
<tr></tr> (white)
<tr></tr> (grey)
<tr></tr> (white)
</table>
```

tr:nth-of-type(even) { grey } wouldn't work for 4 rows:

```
<table>
<tr></tr> (white)
<tr></tr> (grey)
<tr></tr> (white)
<tr></tr> (grey)
</table>
```

Comment: Have you tried `nth-last-of-type` ? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-last-of-type.asp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `:nth-last-of-type()` exists for this purpose:

```
tr:nth-last-of-type(even)
```

However, there isn't a way to provide a fallback for browsers and email clients that don't support this selector with just CSS. You will need to have your application add a class name to the appropriate rows and target by that class instead. If you're unable to modify the application, then you might well be stuck.

Comment: Thanks! 

Yes, we're stuck. The fallback was that I was going to leave them all white. IT can't add any functionality prior to the email generation to count up the panels and then add classes.

Comment: Could you use border-bottom as the fallback?

Comment: @Jennifer Michelle: He's trying to apply backgrounds as opposed to borders.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at MDN, [:nth-last-of-type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3anth-last-of-type) seems to be what you want.

```
tr:nth-last-of-type(even) {background-color: gray}
```

[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KrqsZ/)